# MySQL - Convert unix timestamp to date (Y-m-d) and adjust for timezone for each grouping

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I have a very large table (>5M) where all times are stored as unix timestamps. This is fine in PHP generally, but I'm now running into an issue where I'd like a `date` index to speedup various operations.

The code to convert timestamp to date is easy in PHP, but I can't actually do this on my live server as I'd need to take it offline for hours while I try to run the operation in batches (not going to happen).

This code works almost instantly, which is perfect:

```
UPDATE log 
SET    log_date = Date_format(From_unixtime(log_time), '%Y-%m-%d') 
WHERE  group = '1'
```

But it doesn't offest for timezone. So I thought I could use something like this:

```
# Group 1 
SET global time_zone = '-11:00'; 

UPDATE log 
SET    log_date = Date_format(From_unixtime(log_time), '%Y-%m-%d') 
WHERE  group = '1'; 

# Group 2 
SET global time_zone = '+08:00'; 

UPDATE log 
SET    log_date = Date_format(From_unixtime(log_time), '%Y-%m-%d') 
WHERE  group = '2';
```

But that doesn't seem to work on a per-query basis as when I test the dates it's unaffected by the offset.

Does anyone know how I might offset timezones within MySQL to be able to create this new `date` column?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, all I needed was this:

```
SET time_zone = '-11:00'; # remove `global`
```